# How to code a VBA macro that can copy a row from a local workbook to another workbook in a network drive?

Tags: excel, vba

The excel template I'm working on requires me to transfer data (all text) from a local workbook to a masterfile on a network drive (with an IP address). The macro is preferably on the local file.

The most basic scenario would be having multiple copies of the local workbook used simultaneously on different computers and all the data inputted would be copied to the masterfile on the network via a button in the local files.

Any insight or help is very much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO to treat the master spreadsheet as a database that your local files write to

http://visualbasic.happycodings.com/database-sql-stuff/code14.html

Comment: Thank you sir! This was the first one I tried and it worked perfectly.